# Change a Primary Key to Foreign Key in Toad Data Modeler

Tags: toad

I reverse engineered a MySQL database in Toad Data Modeler 4.3, but there are no foreign keys imported.

What is the easiest way to change the primary keys to Foreign keys?

The only way I know is to create new foreign keys and delete the old ones, but I wonder if there's a better way, especially as the field names are the same (e.g. UserID is the primary key in the Users table, UserID is a foreign key from Users in the Templates table)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is doing with SQL. Something like this should do it for you:

```
ALTER TABLE Templates
ADD CONSTRAINT <name of foreign key> FOREIGN KEY (UserID )
REFERENCES Users (UserID );
```